# What is the Rails Convention for validating field length?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, model, convention

With ActiveRecord models, I know you can validate the length of an input field like so

```
class User
  validates :user_name, length: { maximum: 20 }
end
```

However, one of the design patterns in Rails recommends thin models. If you have a ton of validations, the above code might seem intimidating. I read there was another way you could do this.

You can simply use an `ActiveRecord::Schema` to accomplish the same task.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :user_name, limit: 20
    end
  end
end
```

That accomplishes the exact same thing only you don't even need the second line in your `Users` model.

What is the standard Rails convention regarding this?

Comment: if you want to control the validation do `validates :user_name, length: { maximum: 20 }`, if you let your db control that you will type 100 chars and your db will truncate it, not report an error that the string has more thant 20 chars.

Comment: Some people would argue that you have to have skinny controllers and skinny models. However, this can create several additional classes in your application. Sometimes having a fat model if documented and laid out logically can be easier to read. I will ignore the 'best practices' if it makes the code easier to read as I may not always be the only person touching that code. If the application scales to a point where multiple people will be accessing the same files, I will consider extracting it at that point as a refactor. However, this has rarely been the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people would argue that you have to have skinny controllers and skinny models. However, this can create several additional classes in your application.

Sometimes having a fat model if documented and laid out logically can be easier to read. I will ignore the 'best practices' if it makes the code easier to read as I may not always be the only person touching that code. If the application scales to a point where multiple people will be accessing the same files, I will consider extracting it at that point as a refactor. However, this has rarely been the case.

While it is good to set limits on your database, you also want to have client validations to prevent someone having their data truncated with no feedback to them. For example, (a really horrible example), if you were to limit the username of an User to only six characters and I type in `kobaltz` as my username, I will wonder why my username/password never works as the database truncated it to `kobalt`. You will also run into issues where MySQL (or similar) will throw database level errors which is annoying to fix/troubleshoot. You also have to consider if modifying a database in production, if you set the limits where they did not exist before, you could end up corrupting your data.

Having a few validations in your model does not make it a 'fat' model in my opinion. It makes it easier to read. If you're not using an IDE like RubyMine and only using an editor, you do not have the luxury of `Jump to Definition` which can make the abstraction of your model easier to follow.

Answer (score 2):

If you use second approach, you won't be able to get the error. Its on mysql level and not on model level, so active record won't tell you the reason for user not getting created or updated.

```
object.errors
```

will be empty.

Check this
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Errors/full_messages